# I have to read this html file but the following error is ocuring How to fix this issue?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, lxml

```
url = 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.html

dfs = pd.read_html(url)
```

ImportError: lxml not found, please install it

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Well this sounds so easy, the error (ImportError: lxml not found, please install it) **is that you did not install this lxml library**

You can install this lib so simply, just write pip install lxml in your terminal or cmd.

type:

```
pip install lxml
```